# Does the following binary operation form a group on a set with 3 elements? (multiple identities?)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let S = {a, b, c}.

```
*| a  b  c
-----------
a| a  b  c
b| b  a  a
c| c  a  a
```

This seems to have all the desired characteristics of a group, however, both b and c have two identities. Is (S, *) a group?

Thanks!

Answer:So if one takes element a∈S to be the identity there is actually only one operation that can be can be defined to make (S, *) a group, as each element can only appear in each column and row once. Namely:

```
*| a  b  c
-----------
a| a  b  c
b| b  c  a
c| c  a  b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since there's a row with repeated elements. In particular, the given operation is not associative, since:
$$
b * (c * c) = b * a = b \neq c =  a * c  = (b * c) * c
$$

Comment: Could you link me to a proof of sorts for that 'row with repeated elements' theorem (for lack of a better word)?

Comment: **Claim:** If $x \cdot y = x \cdot z$, then $y = z$. That is, if in row $x$, the elements in columns $y$ and $z$ match, then they must actually have been in the same column (that row has no repeated elements). **Proof:**
\begin{align*}
y &= e \cdot y &\text{identity} \\
&= (x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot y &\text{inverses} \\
&= x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot y) &\text{associativity} \\
&= x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot z) &\text{since } x \cdot y = x \cdot z \\
&= (x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot z &\text{associativity} \\
&= e \cdot z &\text{inverses} \\
&= z &\text{identity} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Thanks! Do you agree with the edit I made to my original post?

Answer (score 1):

In every group $(G,\cdot)$, for all $p,q\in G$ the equation $x \cdot p = q$ has a *unique* solution for $x$, and similarly for $p \cdot x = q$ (although it need not be the same $x$).  This means that the group table must be a "magic square", i.e. each element must occur precisely once in each row and each column.